# Eclipse formatter alignment of comments in switch statement

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I've been experimenting with the code formatter in Eclipse 4.3.2 and have everything set up pretty much the way I want it.  However, Eclipse continues to align comments incorrectly within switch statements, even after I have unchecked both **Enable block comment formatting** and **Enable line comment formatting** in the Comments tab of the formatter options.

Here's a simple example:

```
switch( item )
{
    // Item 1 was selected
    case 1:
        doSomething();
        return true;
    // Item 2 was selected
    case 2:
        doSomethingElse();
        return true;
    // Selected item was not 1 or 2
    default:
        return false;
}
```

When the formatter runs, the comments are shifted:

```
switch( item )
{
// Item 1 was selected
    case 1:
        doSomething();
        return true;
        // Item 2 was selected
    case 2:
        doSomethingElse();
        return true;
        // Selected item was not 1 or 2
    default:
        return false;
}
```

It seems like the formatter wants to align the first comment with the opening brace of the `switch` and make each subsequent comment a part of the preceding `case` block.  But that's not what I want, and I can't seem to figure out how to make Eclipse leave these comments alone.  I could use the `@formatter:off` tag to disable formatting of this section entirely, but that's not ideal because I still do want the formatter to run on this code.  I'm particularly confused as to why the formatter is realigning comments at all, given that I unchecked the options to do so.

Comment: Those formatting preferences control formatting *the* *comments*, their text, not the positioning of the start of the comment. You're just seeing it maintain the indentation of the previous line.

Comment: @nitind Thanks for the clarification.  That makes sense, although in that case the wording of the options is confusing (at least to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that using `break` instead of `return` solves the problem, except for the very first comment which still gets aligned with the opening brace of the `switch` statement.

I filed a bug report with Eclipse but it was marked a duplicate.  It turns out there was already an Eclipse bug report for this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=124622

The bug report was filed in 2006, last commented on in 2008, and the bug remains in Eclipse some 6 years and 7 versions later.  Guess they just don't care.

Answer (score 0):

Do all line/block comments shift like this or does it happen only with switch body? Either way, this looks like a bug in the formatter to me, did you check bugs.eclipse.org for a bug similar to this?

Comment: I've only noticed it in `switch` statements, but in most other instances (where it doesn't do this) the comment is preceded by a blank line, so perhaps that is problem.  I have confirmed that it happens consistently in every `switch` where I have commented the code in this manner.  I did look for a bug but did not find one.  I'll open a bug with the Eclipse team and see what they say.  Thanks.